# Cefsharp3-WinForms x64 shows blank page but x86 works

Tags: winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have issues with initializing CefSharp3. The control give a blank page after initializing.
I follow the instructions from CefSharp Wiki page (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start and http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application)
The problem is that when I build the application for x64 i get a blank page, but it works fine in x86.

The only code in my WinForms project is this:

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

public void InitializeChromium()
{
   CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
   // Initialize cef with the provided settings
   Cef.Initialize(settings);
   // Create a browser component
   chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://ourcodeworld.com");
   // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
   this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
   chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     // Start the browser after initialize global component
     InitializeChromium();
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     Cef.Shutdown();
}
```

I also tried adding a panel, and initializing ChromiumBrowser in the panel with `panel1.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser)` instead of `this.Controls.add(chromeBrowser)`, but the issue is still there.

I found this in the troubleshooting section at CefSharp wiki:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting

> b) The developer tools. Add a button to your form and make a call to "browser.ShowDevTools()". If you can see a document has loaded and you have a DOM in there, then your problem is a display output one and your most likely problem is one of not setting 'Dock' correctly, or some other setting is causing the browser to render offscreen/headless. If you get a blank tool window, or no tool window at all, then CefSharp has failed to initialize correctly, so you have a set-up issue to troubleshoot.

This is exactly the symptoms that I experience.

I tried creating the same project on my laptop (MacBook Pro with Win7, VS2013 and .NET 4.5.2) and it worked like a charm. This means something is up with my workstation (win10, VS2015 .NET 4.5.3).

Any ideas?

Comment: Iv'e got the same issue, and I'm trying to solve it.  Not found a way yet, but you just put me on to getting it working in X86, tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the latest build.  The solution for now is to use the v51.0.0 build.

You can do this quite easily in the NuGet package manager in VS2015, or if your using VS2013, use the "--version 51.0.0" option when installing cefsharp from the package manager command line.

The issue for the problem is here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1870

Keep an eye on the issue for future solutions.

## Update 28/11/2016

This is a bug in the current V53 release of CefSharp.  It's been confirmed by the CefSharp team and is addressed in issue #1819 (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1819)

The bug has been apparently fixed, but will not be released until V55.

The solution for now, is to either go back to V51 or to build your own version from source for V55.

Comment: It's actually a bug in `Chromium` if you follow the links listed.

Comment: indeed, but for here the description suffices :-)

Comment: It's important that people understand that `CefSharp` is just a wrapper and lots of bugs are `upstream` issues with either `CEF` or `Chromium`.

Comment: aggreed, and I think the issue/bug track highlights that very well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I installed version 51 and the problem is gone.